# Want to animate the first slides of multiple cycles with one pager

Tags: cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using [two Cycle slideshows with a single pager](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager-double.html) and different effects on each slideshow (with the metadata plugin).

I would also like to animate the first slide of each slideshow as documented [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/fade-in-first.html), but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

This is my current js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').each(function(index) {
        $(this).cycle({
            pager:  '#pager',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
                if (index == 0)
                    // for first slideshow, return a new anchro
                    return '<a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a>';
                // for 2nd slideshow, select the anchor created previously
                return '#pager a:eq('+i+')';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The effects are coded on the .slideshow divs (with the metadata plugin)

```
<div class="slideshow { fx: 'scrollRight', timeout: 0, cleartypeNoBg: true, speed: 750, easing: 'easeInOutBack' }">
<div class="slideshow { fx: 'scrollLeft', timeout: 0, cleartypeNoBg: true, speed: 750, easing: 'easeInOutBack' }">
```